# Generalization of Gauss-Markov theorem for nonlinear least squares

Tags: references, mathematical-statistics, regression, least-squares

Consider the following very general framework: There is an unknown vector $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a function $f\colon\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, $m\geq n$. There are measurements $\mu\in\mathbb{R}^m$ of $f(x)$ given. We assume the measurements to be independent and identically distributed. Our goal is to give a good estimator for $x$. If $f$ is a linear function there is the Gauss-Markov theorem which tells us that the solution of the least square problem $\text{argmin}_y  \|f(y)-\mu\|^2_2$ yields the best linear unbiased estimator. If $f$ is nonlinear but such that the least square problem has a unique solution we can still define an estimator as the solution of this least square problem. What can be said about this estimator? Is it optimal in some sense? Can it be improved? It is easy to see that this estimator will in general be biased. Can this be fixed? Since this framework is too broad I would also be happy to get some advices for special cases of $f$. As a toy example one could consider for example $m=n=1$ and $f(x)=x^2$.

Comment: We usually model it using GLM or spline models, such a definition of "nonlinear BLUE" is not very useful.